# Creating object with string options

Tags: javascript

I wish to create an empty object like an array as below but to have string options to set also. How do I initialize it so its empty until I set anything to it?

```
var vehicles = [ ];

vehicles[3].type = '7';
vehicles[3].license = 'HKD56YHF';

vehicles[1].type = '2';
vehicles[1].license = 'JF755HJ';
```

So say a console log could be done like this:

```
console.log(vehicle[3].type);
console.log(vehicle[1].type);
```

or any [n] of 'vehicle'

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [Ninas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61520094/12537815) you can also combine the object creation and property setting into one step:

```js
var vehicles = [];
vehicles[1] = {
    type: '7',
    license: 'JF755HJ'
};

// or...

vehicles.push({
    type: '7',
    license: 'JF755HJ'
});
```

Of course, you can also do everything in one step:

```js
var vehicles = [
    {
        type: '7',
        license: 'JF755HJ'
    },
    // ... more objects ...
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign an object first as element of the array and then assign to a property.

```js
var vehicles = [ ];

vehicles[3] = {};
vehicles[3].type = '7';
vehicles[3].license = 'HKD56YHF';

vehicles[1] = {}
vehicles[1].type = '2';
vehicles[1].license = 'JF755HJ';


console.log(vehicles[3].type);
console.log(vehicles[1].type);
console.log(vehicles);
```